# lunr: how to add a new trimmer

Tags: node.js, lunrjs

I want to add a trimmer (called improvedTrimmer) before the multilanguage one added by lunr-language. What I'm not able to find is how to pass the existing function to `this.pipeline.before()` or `this.pipeline.after()`. Here are my attempts that always throw "Error: Cannot find existingFn":

```
fullTextIndex = lunr(function() {

    this.use(lunr.multiLanguage("en", "it"));

    // This works, but put my trimmer at the end of the pipeline
    // this.pipeline.add(improvedTrimmer);

    // This says lunr.trimmer not found. Idem with this.trimmer
    // this.pipeline.after(lunr.trimmer, improvedTrimmer);

    // This seems the most logical choice, but no way (the string is
    // the synthesized trimmer label by the multilanguage plugin
    // this.pipeline.before("lunr-multi-trimmer-en-it", improvedTrimmer);

    // This works, but seems very a dirty workaround
    this.pipeline.after(this.pipeline._stack[0], improvedTrimmer);
```

Around on the web there are few suggestions that do not work with the current version of lunr.

Comment: It seems like you need a `lunr.Pipeline#prepend` method? Feel free to open an issue (or better yet a PR) at https://github.com/olivernn/lunr.js